# Insert coordinates to mysql from android

Tags: android, mysql, gps, location

I have found a tutorial about gps location service.
Every thing works fine.
The next thing I want to write is passing coordinates form app to mysql.
I have tried several tutorial about android mysql but i dont know how to applied them to this code.

What I am trying to achieve is to onLocationChanged send latitude and longitude to database.

Could someone tell me how to do this?

This is the code:

connect.php

```
<?php
 define('HOST','localhost');
 define('USER','');
 define('PASS','');
 define('DB','coordinates');

 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
 ?>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $la = $_POST['la_string'];
    $lo = $_POST['lo_string'];   

    $get_result = $con->query("INSERT INTO gps(la,lo) VALUES ('$la','$lo')"); 

    if($get_result === true){
    echo "Successfully Registered";
    }else{
    echo "Not Registered";
    }
}else{
    echo 'error';
}
```

?>

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button start, stop, exit;
private TextView data_lo, text_lo, text_la, data_la;
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
private String la_string,lo_string;





@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (broadcastReceiver == null) {
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                data_la.setText("" + intent.getExtras().get("latitude"));
                data_lo.setText("" + intent.getExtras().get("longitude"));

            }
        };
    }

    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("location_update"));

}




@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(broadcastReceiver != null){
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    data_la = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data_la);
    data_lo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data_lo);
    text_la = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_la);
    text_lo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_lo);
    exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);



    if(!runtime_permissions())
        enable_buttons();

}

private void enable_buttons() {

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GPS_Service.class);
            startService(i);
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GPS_Service.class);
            stopService(i);

        }
    });

}

private boolean runtime_permissions() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission
                    (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission
                    (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},100);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode == 100){
        if( grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            enable_buttons();
        }else {
            runtime_permissions();
        }
    }
}}
```

GPS_Service.java

```
public class GPS_Service extends Service {


private LocationListener locationListener;
private LocationManager locationManager;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
            i.putExtra("latitude", location.getLatitude());
            i.putExtra("longitude", location.getLongitude());
            sendBroadcast(i);




        }






        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //noinspection MissingPermission
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,0,locationListener);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(locationManager != null){
        //noinspection MissingPermission
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a call via HttpClient to your server and send your data through that as Post with your data encoded.

```
try{
        String data  = URLEncoder.encode("la_string", "UTF-8") + "=" +
           URLEncoder.encode(data_la.text, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("lo_string", "UTF-8") + "=" + 
           URLEncoder.encode(data_lo.text, "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL(URL);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write( data );
        wr.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
           InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response if you have something to do with it
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           sb.append(line);
           break;
        }

        return sb.toString();
     } catch(Exception e){
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
     }
```

You can see a complete example here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

Comment: I still don't understand, where do I have put this code. In MainActivity or in GPS_Service

Comment: it depends on when you want to call the server to store the values

Comment: In app i have two buttons, start and stop. I click start, wait for coordinates. Update time is every 3 seconds.  
I would like to store values automatically every time when the location is changed.

Comment: So call the method when you receive the information of the changed location, I believe it is on your onReceive of your BroadcastReceiver. IDK what is the entire scenario but keep in mind that you will be calling the server every 3 seconds. Another way would be that you save all the changed location values in a temporary array and on the stop button you sent the array to the server but it depends on what you have to do with the data and in which moment.